# PHP: foreach insert into, a exploded-list

Tags: php

Everything seems correct, but nothing happens.
I want to INSERT a PHP exploded keyword list.
into
the new table, (already working/ OK):
**product_keywords**

```
product_id     keyword
```

from my old table
**PRODUCTS,**

```
product_id     keywords (a comma-list)
```

Where is the error(?)

**explode echo TEST (already working/ OK)**

```
$teile_arr = explode(",", $stringx);

foreach($teile_arr as $keyword){
echo " ID: ".$res_id[$i]."<br>";
echo "KW: ".$keyword."<br>";
}
```

**html echo TEST result OK:**

```
KW: Christmas
ID: 544405
KW: tree
ID: 544405
KW: Santa
ID: 544405
```

**display input echo (already working/ OK)**

```
foreach($teile_arr as $keyword){
echo "<input type='text' name='keyword".$res_id[$i]."' value='".$keyword."'>";
}
```

**not working, table is still empty**
PHP does not insert any content in the database.
There must be a problem with "foreach" at this point.

```
foreach($teile_arr as $keyword){
$sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO product_keywords SET product_id='".$res_id[$i]."', keyword='".$keyword."";
$db->execute($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert statements use `VALUES`, update statements use `SET`.

```
"INSERT IGNORE INTO product_keywords SET product_id='".$res_id[$i]."', keyword='".$keyword."";
```

Should be

```
"INSERT IGNORE INTO product_keywords(product_id,keyword) VALUES ('{$res_id[$i]}', '{$keyword}')";
```

Also, you should be using prepared statements to protect from sql injection attacks.

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1)